# When is Avani Avittam (Upakarma) this year?

Tags: rituals, astrology, festivals, brahmins, calendar

As I discuss in [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/19369/36), Avani Avittam aka Upakarma, is a ritual performed on the Dakshinayana day in August where Brahmanas change their sacred thread.  At least it usually occurs in August.  But I'm seeing claims on some websites (like [this one](http://www.drikpanchang.com/ceremony/upakarma/yajurveda/yajurveda-upakarma-date-time.html)) that this year, it will occur on July 28.  And I'm seeing claims on other websites (like [this one](https://www.templepurohit.com/festival/yajurveda-upakarma/)) that it will occur on August 7.

So my question is, when exactly will Avani Avittam occur this year?  Does it differ between Rig Veda and Yajur Veda?  And does it differ for America and India?

I think all this confusion may be due to the fact that there will be a massive lunar eclipse in August this year, so that throws things off.

Comment: Yes, it does differ by Veda, see this related [question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17315/what-is-the-reason-behind-the-differences-between-samaveda-%C4%80va%E1%B9%87i-avi%E1%B9%AD%E1%B9%ADam-and-oth)

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan Yeah, Samaveda Brahmins always do it at a different time.  But at least Rig and Yajur Veda Brahmins do it around the same time.  I'm a Krishna Yajur Veda Brahmin, so I'm trying to figure out when I'm supposed to do it this year.

Comment: AFAIK, for Samaveda Brahmins it is on the day of Hastha Nakshatram that marks Vinayakar Chathurthi.

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan Yeah, typically the Sama Veda one is about two weeks after everyone else.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I think sAmveda UpAkarma is sometime in August this year.

Comment: @Yogi OK, but I'm looking for the Yajur Veda date.

Comment: Related [post](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/14494/277).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usual date for krishna and shulka yajurvedas would be 7th August (shrAvana poornima). But because the eclipse is occurring in India. Hence they have pre-poned the event to 28th July , Hasta Nakshatra.

So those who living in America do not need to follow this date and should do on the normal date i.e 7th of August.

For those living in India, Australia, Africa should do the upAkarma along with Rig veda people i.e 28th July.

If there occurs Eclipse and sankranti when sun enters Leo (masa pirrapu/avani 1st in Tamil) during purnima,the people having upakrama for that day should be finished prior to punima when hasta nakshatra is available(generally shravana shukla Panchami/shashti.and for samaveda,if there is sankramana(purattasi 1st) to kanya in bhadrapada then shraavana month's hasta should be considered. ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upakarma))

Answer (score 0):

Avani Avittam -2017 - It will Fall on 28th July 2017 (Friday)

Upakarma means beginning or Arambham and it refers to the ritualistic beginning of learning Veda. Apart from learning Vedas on Upakarma day, Brahmins ritually change their Upanayana thread along with Shrauta rituals. Upakarma which is a Vedic ritual is still practiced by Hindus of Brahmin community.

Those who follow 'Yajurveda' observe the 'Upakarma' on the full moon day during 'Shravana' month i.e. on 'Shravana Purnima' day. Those who follow 'Rigveda' observe the 'Upakarma' on 'Shravana Nakshatra' day in the month of 'Shravana'. Hence the day to observe 'Upakarma' might differ for the followers of 'Yajurveda' and 'Rigveda'.

Upakarma is known as Avani Avittam in Tamil Nadu. For those who do their first Upakarma, it is known as Thalai Avani Avittam. In Andhra Pradesh, Upakarma during Shravana Purnima is known as Jandhyala Purnima.

Brahmins choose the day of Shravana Purnima to begin the study of Vedas as the day coincides with Hayagriva Jayanti. Hayagriva Jayanti is the birth anniversary of Lord Hayagriva who is considered the incarnation of Lord Vishnu. It is believed that Lord Hayagriva restored all Vedas to Brahma.

The main purpose of the Upakarma ritual is to offer prayers and express the gratitude to those Rishis who gave the knowledge of Vedas and revealed Vedic Mantras to the mankind. The next day of Upakarma is known as Gayatri Japam day.

Those who follow Samaveda observe the Upakarma on Hasta Nakshatra day during Bhadrapada month. Samaveda Upakarma day usually falls after fortnight of Yajurveda and Rigveda Upakarma day.

Comment: "In Andhra Pradesh, Upakarma during Shravana Purnima is known as Jandhyala Purnima" This term is not used by those actually performing the upakarma :-D